# How to convert varchar into date datatype in inline functions sql

Tags: sql-server

```
create table session12 
(
     id int,
     name varchar(20),
     Dateofbirth varchar(20)
);

insert into session12 
values (1, 'prashanth', '29/06/1995'),
       (2, 'rayala', '27/06/1997'),
       (3, 'rayala1213', '7/9/2000');

create function inline_Getsession()
returns table
as
    return
        select 
            id, name,
            cast(Dateofbirth as date) as DOB 
        from session12;

select * 
from inline_Getsession();
```

Output:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Quite simply - DON'T DO THIS. Fix your schema and use the correct datatype. A date of birth is not a string, it is a DATE (and not a datetime or datetime2). To understand why this is a problem, just search the internet (or just this website) for the error message. The topic is asked every single day!

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to use `CONVERT` and a style code:

```
CONVERT(date,DateOfBirth,103)
```

103 style means the UK style (`dd/MM/yyyy`). You can find a full list of the styles in the [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation.

Comment: You're right @UnhandledExcepSean. I spend too much time converting from `MM/dd/yyyy` on SO that I was in autopilot :)

Comment: 104 = `dd.mm.yyyy` while 103=`dd/mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
create table session12 (id int,name varchar(20),Dateofbirth varchar(20));`

insert into session12 values(1,'prashanth','29/06/1995');
insert into session12 values(2,'rayala','27/06/1997');
insert into session12 values(3,'rayala1213','7/9/2000');

create function inline_Getsession()
Returns Table
as
Return
select id,name,CONVERT(DATE,Dateofbirth,103) as DOB from session12;

select * from inline_Getsession();
```

You need to provide a date format of 103 when converting `dd/mm/yyyy` to date

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the `DateFormat to DMY`

If 2012+, I would suggest using `try_convert(date,...)` to avoid throwing an error for any bogus strings.

**Example**

```
Declare @session12 table (id int,name varchar(20),Dateofbirth varchar(20));
insert into @session12 values(1,'prashanth','29/06/1995');
insert into @session12 values(2,'rayala','27/06/1997');
insert into @session12 values(3,'rayala1213','7/9/2000');

Set DateFormat DMY
Select *
      ,AsADate = convert(date,DateOfBirth)
 From  @session12
```

Returns

```
id  name        Dateofbirth   AsADate
1   prashanth   29/06/1995    1995-06-29
2   rayala      27/06/1997    1997-06-27
3   rayala1213  7/9/2000      2000-09-07
```